# Unable to use ng-changeto call function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi had a small functionality where on change of number the value should be multiplied ..but now it is not working..
Can someone help me which is quite simple

Tag

```
 <input type="number" class="form-control text-right" ng-model="totalPremium" ng-change="result()"></input>
```

Controller

```
$scope.result = function() => {
return $scope.totalPremium*5;

    };
```

Thanks

Please look the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5q8q5mu/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Module and App name is not set in your fiddle

Set module

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('TodoCtrl', TodoCtrl);
```

Set app name

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
```

Controller same as before

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
$scope.result = function() {
return $scope.totalPremium*5;

    };    
    };
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/h5q8q5mu/12/)